# Display image alt text in when printing

Tags: css, image, alt

I would like to display image alt text instead of image when printing the webpage. I tried this but it doesn't work, probably because img doesn't have a closing tag so the pseudo-elements doesn't work with img. Is there a way to do this?

```
@media print {
       img::after {
       content: "attr(alt)";
       }
}
```

Comment: Without JavaScript not possible. Because `<img>` is a void, and pseudo-elements don't apply, that's correct. I usually have each `<img>` in a `<figure>` with a `<figcaption>` so it's pretty simple for any new modifications. Another element that can used as an `<img>` and has an end tag is `<object>` (if semantics isn't a concern).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are assigning `::after` to `img`.

`img` can't have a child. So you can not set `::after ::before` to it.

you can do this:

**index.html:**

```
<div data-alt="some-text-in-here">
    <img src="url" alt="some-text-in-here">
</div>
```

**style.css:**

```
@media print {
    div {
        position: relative;
    }

    div::after {
        content: attr(data-alt);

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        /* more styles */
     }

}
```